# How to use Selenium to get different currencies from a website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn Selenium in python to **scrape** euro prices from the website below (I am located outside Europe). If I just parse the html using beautiful soup, it will always give me Prices in dollar. I was told Selenium can present the html code as it is displayed (so I can scrape the Euro prices) but not quite sure how to do it

My code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = "https://www.colmar.it/en-gb/Man/Ski/Jackets/C352"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
```

Then traverse the data with BeautifulSoup with the code below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
price = []
for price_tag in soup.find_all('span', class_='product-preview__old-price'):
        price.append(price_tag.text)
```

Since my location is outside Europe, it always give me prices in Dollar :(

Is there a way to obtain the html as I see it (when I change the delivery region on the website to Europe)?

****EDIT****: I have tried to adjust the language to French but still with no success. Full code below. Any other recommendations?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = "https://www.colmar.it/en-gb/Man/Ski/Jackets/C352"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=fr");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
price = []
for price_tag in soup.find_all('span', class_='product-preview__old-price'):
        price.append(price_tag.text)
```

Comment: Adjust your script to change the country before you execute getting of prices

Comment: Thanks. any tips on doing that?

Comment: Check out the docs over here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html You'll need to locate the elements on the screen/ webpage and then perform `click` events on them. Then navigate to your desired page and read the price as you were doing before

Comment: Changing the language of your browser will not always change the language of the webpage

Comment: it uses cookie `usrIpCountry:"FR"` to set country and display Euro. It gets data as JSON from https://www.colmar.it//Assets/Colmar/json/productlist-en-gb.json

Comment: @furas damn that's good tips. I've managed to get Euro prices using `usrIpCountry:"FR"` and requests. How did you know the cookie was available? I have different websites I'm gonna try it on

Comment: also @furas, how did you manage to obtain the JSON link?

Comment: I use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab `Network`) to see all requests from browser to server. When I filtered to display only `XHR` (`AJAX`) requests then I get this url and I could see what it gets in response - and I saw `CurrencySymbol` in JSON . It is popular method to use XHR (AJAX) to set data on page. In DevTools I could also see all headers - ie. cookies - to see what it sends to server when I change Country on page - and I saw cookie with 'FR`

Comment: BTW: sometimes I use local proxy server [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and set in browser this proxy server - and then I can see all requests in `Charles`. Some people use as local proxy server: [mitm](https://mitmproxy.org/) (created in Python) or very complex [BurpSuit](https://portswigger.net/burp) (`Commmunity` editon is free)

Comment: that makes sense. just trying to cement all this new found knowledge, if following your guide and I go to Moncler US Version (https://www.moncler.com/gb/us/) then I want to change to extract euro from France again, I can use this cookie VISIT:"SITE_CODE=MONCLER_FR" ?

Comment: when I visit Moclear in browser I can change language and currency using link "Shipping to: FR" or "Shop in: FR" and it changes url https://moncler.com/gb/us to https://moncler.com/fr and later to https://store.moncler.com/fr-fr - so I don't have to use cookies to change currency - I have to use url https://store.moncler.com/fr-fr . When I visit page with one product and check XHR in DevTools the I see it reads Euro price from url which have `siteCode=MONCLER_FR`. If I use the same url but with `siteCode=MONCLER_US` then I get price in US Dollars. And for `siteCode=MONCLER_GB` I get `GBP`

Comment: I tested it only in web browser and DevTool and I don't know how it would work in Python's code with `requests`. Maybe it would need only urls with `siteCode=MONCLER_FR` too.

Comment: @umm I posted the solution that worked for me below, please let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a cookie with a certain country, try:

```
url = "https://www.colmar.it/en-gb/Man/Ski/Jackets/C352"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

# Delete current country cookie
driver.delete_cookie('usrIpCountry')
# Set a cookie with country France
driver.add_cookie({'name':'usrIpCountry', 'value':'France', 'domain': 'www.colmar.it'})

# Refresh before proceeding
driver.refresh()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
price = []
for price_tag in soup.find_all('span', class_='product-preview__old-price'):
        price.append(price_tag.text)
```

This should make it. Good luck!